# Is there any risk in using your k8s masters as ingress nodes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

By default most people seem to avoid running anything on the masters. These nodes are less likely to be re-provisioned or moved around than the rest of the cluster. It would make them a perfect fit for ingress controllers.

Is there any security and/or management implications/risks in using the masters as ingress nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always, the risk is that if your Ingress Controller eats all your IOPS (or memory or CPU but in this case it would probably be IOPS) then your control plane can go unavailable, leaving you fewer ways to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Security wise you also might not want to expose your master Nodes to external traffic (outside your datacenter) at all.